# How To Make Excel Hyperlinks Visit In Browser ONLY When Special Key Is Held And Mouse Clicked

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I deal with tons of spreadsheets for doing SEO that contain tons of different URLs and domains.

Of course I know how to manually select a region of spreadsheet and click "remove hyperlinks".

But I need a more advanced setup.

How can I program excel so that:

1. In every spreadsheet I create ever, by complete default, no cells EVER turn into automatic hyperlinks that cause browser to open and visit when clicked

   2. I designate a special keyboard shortcut that when held and mouse clicked on cell, it WILL visit that hyperlink in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Step **1** can be achieved by setting the AutoCorrect options to not build "hot" hyperlink:

[image]

So clear that first checkbox.

Step **2** can be achieved by using an event macro, like the double-click event.